# Linq updating existing record

Tags: c#, linq

I need to update the existing record in linq if the record exists elese add a new one.
will saveChanges() work for both? if yes how to differentiate between updation and insertion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 1):

`SaveChanges()` performs all changes you made to a data base since the last call. This includes:

- Adding new items to a collection
- Deleting items from a collection
- Changing properties

So, you have either to add the record to a collection or to get the existing one and modify its properties. There is no general method to do this point. After you performed the changes, call `SaveChanges()` to save them.

Answer (score 0):

Linq in general is for *querying* not for modification (it stands for Language Integrated **Query** after all)  - ideally you do not want to create any side effects. Updating and insertion differ in that for updating you usually will have to query for an existing record to well.. update - for insertion you just add it. And yes `SaveChanges()` will work for both in that it commits your changes and additions to the underlying data store.

Your question is very broad - without a particular code that you are struggling with its hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: The OP is about LINQ to Entities (or LINQ to SQL), which despite the similar name are not a querying framework, they're an ORM.

Comment: Linq to Entities is using the same extension methods defined in `Queryable` which are part of Linq so the argument holds - what exactly is the downvote for? There's no argument that EF is an ORM, but the querying part, Linq to Entities is just that - **for querying**.

Comment: Your complaint that people shouldn't use LINQ to Entities to update their data is unfounded. The OP was not seeking a LINQ statement that would update or insert; it was seeking the correct method to update and insert records in the LINQ to Entities ORM

Comment: You don't update data with Linq to Entities - you query for the data that you want to update, then you update the record. Updating is not part of Linq to Entities since it is simply an `IQueryable` provider. It is part of Entity Framework as a whole though which is what the ORM is called.

Comment: Point taken. Change your answer to include that, and I wouldn't have anything to downvote.